# ORA-20013: DBMS_QOPATCH ran mostly in non install area

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, patching

I have problems with patching p23054246_121020_Linux-x86-64 on an oracle database 12.1.0.2.0 on a Red Hat Enterprise 7.2. The patch installation seems to work but when I do the datapatch it fails:

```
-bash-4.2$ ./datapatch -verbose SQL Patching tool version 12.1.0.2.0 on Wed Aug 31 16:29:31 2016 Copyright (c) 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Log file for this invocation: /opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/sqlpatch/sqlpatch_22950_2016_08_31_16_29_31/sqlpatch_invocation.log

Connecting to database...OK Bootstrapping registry and package to current versions...done

Queryable inventory could not determine the current opatch status. Execute 'select dbms_sqlpatch.verify_queryable_inventory from dual' and/or check the invocation log /opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/sqlpatch/sqlpatch_22950_2016_08_31_16_29_31/sqlpatch_invocation.log for the complete error. Prereq check failed, exiting without installing any patches.

Please refer to MOS Note 1609718.1 and/or the invocation log /opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/sqlpatch/sqlpatch_22950_2016_08_31_16_29_31/sqlpatch_invocation.log for information on how to resolve the above errors.

SQL Patching tool complete on Wed Aug 31 16:29:34 2016
```

Following the instruction:

```
Connected to: Oracle Database 12c Standard Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0
- 64bit Production

SQL> select dbms_sqlpatch.verify_queryable_inventory from dual;

VERIFY_QUERYABLE_INVENTORY
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
ORA-20013: DBMS_QOPATCH ran mostly in non install area
```

Reading online recommendations I should check the directory `OPATCH_SCRIPT_DIR`, `OPATCH_LOG_DIR`, `OPATCH_INST_DIR`. They seem to be correct. How to solve this?

---

I rolled back the patch and apply p21948354_121020_Linux-x86-64 from January.

```
/opt/oracle/product/12cR1/db/OPatch/opatch lsinventory
/opt/oracle/product/12cR1/db/OPatch/datapatch -apply 21948354 -force
```

That seem to work with no errors. Database confirms the patch.

I appyed p23054246_121020_Linux-x86-64 again from July.

```
/opt/oracle/product/12cR1/db/OPatch/opatch lsinventory
/opt/oracle/product/12cR1/db/OPatch/datapatch -apply 23054246 -force
```

Patch is applied but with Errors:

```
Patch 23054246 apply: WITH ERRORS
  logfile: /opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/sqlpatch/23054246/20213895/23054246_apply_xxx_2016Sep01_14_54_16.log (errors)
    Error at line 32893: ORA-04042: Prozedur, Funktion, Package oder Package Body ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 33126: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 33149: ORA-06550: Zeile 5, Spalte 37:
    Error at line 33151: ORA-06550: Zeile 5, Spalte 1:
    Error at line 33171: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 33194: ORA-06550: Zeile 5, Spalte 37:
    Error at line 33196: ORA-06550: Zeile 5, Spalte 1:
    Error at line 33227: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 33256: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 33281: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 33310: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 33349: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 33373: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 33400: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 33425: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 33459: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 33489: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 33519: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 33549: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 33581: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 33609: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 33633: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 33663: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 33694: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 33728: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 33754: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 33786: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 33818: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 33848: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 33873: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 33932: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 34160: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 34230: ORA-01918: Benutzer 'DVSYS' ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 39029: Warning: View created with compilation errors.
    Error at line 39078: Warning: View created with compilation errors.
    Error at line 39134: Warning: View created with compilation errors.
    Error at line 39184: Warning: View created with compilation errors.
    Error at line 39243: Warning: View created with compilation errors.
    Error at line 39296: Warning: View created with compilation errors.
    Error at line 39376: Warning: View created with compilation errors.
    Error at line 39430: Warning: View created with compilation errors.
    Error at line 39478: Warning: View created with compilation errors.
    Error at line 39525: Warning: View created with compilation errors.
    Error at line 39639: Warning: View created with compilation errors.
    Error at line 39686: Warning: View created with compilation errors.
    Error at line 39731: Warning: View created with compilation errors.
    Error at line 39776: Warning: View created with compilation errors.
    Error at line 39840: Warning: View created with compilation errors.
    Error at line 45396: ORA-04042: Prozedur, Funktion, Package oder Package Body ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 45404: ORA-04042: Prozedur, Funktion, Package oder Package Body ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 45412: ORA-04042: Prozedur, Funktion, Package oder Package Body ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 45420: ORA-04042: Prozedur, Funktion, Package oder Package Body ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 45428: ORA-04042: Prozedur, Funktion, Package oder Package Body ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 45436: ORA-04042: Prozedur, Funktion, Package oder Package Body ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 45444: ORA-04042: Prozedur, Funktion, Package oder Package Body ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 45452: ORA-04042: Prozedur, Funktion, Package oder Package Body ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 45461: ORA-04042: Prozedur, Funktion, Package oder Package Body ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 45469: ORA-04042: Prozedur, Funktion, Package oder Package Body ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 45850: ORA-04042: Prozedur, Funktion, Package oder Package Body ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 45859: ORA-04042: Prozedur, Funktion, Package oder Package Body ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 45867: ORA-04042: Prozedur, Funktion, Package oder Package Body ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 46653: ORA-04042: Prozedur, Funktion, Package oder Package Body ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 46660: ORA-04042: Prozedur, Funktion, Package oder Package Body ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 46667: ORA-04042: Prozedur, Funktion, Package oder Package Body ist nicht vorhanden
    Error at line 46970: ORA-01400: Einfugen von NULL in ("SYS"."OBJAUTH$"."OBJ#") nicht moglich
    Error at line 47882: ORA-06550: Zeile 9, Spalte 24:
    Error at line 47884: ORA-06550: Zeile 9, Spalte 6:
    Error at line 47901: ORA-06550: Zeile 2, Spalte 21:
    Error at line 47903: ORA-06550: Zeile 2, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 47920: ORA-06550: Zeile 2, Spalte 21:
    Error at line 47922: ORA-06550: Zeile 2, Spalte 3:
    Error at line 48067: ORA-06550: Zeile 2, Spalte 11:
    Error at line 48068: PLS-00201: identifier 'DVSYS.DV$FACTOR' must be declared
    Error at line 48069: ORA-06550: Zeile 2, Spalte 11:
    Error at line 48071: ORA-06550: Zeile 3, Spalte 12:
    Error at line 48072: PLS-00201: identifier 'DVSYS.DV$FACTOR' must be declared
    Error at line 48073: ORA-06550: Zeile 3, Spalte 12:
    Error at line 48075: ORA-06550: Zeile 4, Spalte 18:
    Error at line 48076: PLS-00201: identifier 'DVSYS.DV$FACTOR' must be declared
    Error at line 48077: ORA-06550: Zeile 4, Spalte 18:
    Error at line 48079: ORA-06550: Zeile 10, Spalte 20:
    Error at line 48081: ORA-06550: Zeile 9, Spalte 9:
    Error at line 48083: ORA-06550: Zeile 14, Spalte 9:
    Error at line 48084: PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or
    Error at line 48086: ORA-06550: Zeile 14, Spalte 9:
    Error at line 48088: ORA-06550: Zeile 15, Spalte 9:
    Error at line 48089: PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or
    Error at line 48091: ORA-06550: Zeile 15, Spalte 9:
    Error at line 48093: ORA-06550: Zeile 20, Spalte 24:
    Error at line 48094: PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or
    Error at line 48096: ORA-06550: Zeile 20, Spalte 13:
    Error at line 48098: ORA-06550: Zeile 24, Spalte 32:
    Error at line 48099: PLS-00201: identifier 'DVSYS.DBMS_MACUTL' must be declared
    Error at line 48100: ORA-06550: Zeile 23, Spalte 13:
    Error at line 48102: ORA-06550: Zeile 26, Spalte 24:
    Error at line 48103: PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or
    Error at line 48105: ORA-06550: Zeile 26, Spalte 13:
    Error at line 48107: ORA-06550: Zeile 30, Spalte 61:
    Error at line 48108: PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or
    Error at line 48110: ORA-06550: Zeile 30, Spalte 13:

Please refer to MOS Note 1609718.1 and/or the invocation log
/opt/oracle/cfgtoollogs/sqlpatch/sqlpatch_29825_2016_09_01_14_54_14/sqlpatch_invocation.log
for information on how to resolve the above errors.
```

Seem no good solution to force it.

Comment: Try using the -force option on datapatch

Comment: Force does not work. -bash-4.2$ ./datapatch -force
SQL Patching tool version 12.1.0.2.0 on Thu Sep  1 12:51:36 2016
Copyright (c) 2016, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to database...OK
Determining current state...done
Adding patches to installation queue and performing prereq checks...done
Installation queue:
  Nothing to roll back
  Nothing to apply

SQL Patching tool complete on Thu Sep  1 12:51:38 2016

Comment: That doesn't seem to have found the patch

Comment: Path is correct: SQL> select DIRECTORY_NAME, DIRECTORY_PATH from dba_directories where DIRECTORY_NAME like '%OPATCH%';

OPATCH_LOG_DIR
/opt/oracle/product/12cR1/db/QOpatch

OPATCH_SCRIPT_DIR
/opt/oracle/product/12cR1/db/QOpatch

OPATCH_INST_DIR
/opt/oracle/product/12cR1/db/OPatch


SQL> !
bash-4.2$ echo $ORACLE_HOME
/opt/oracle/product/12cR1/db

Comment: Think you are getting an unrelated error this time, does the database think the data patch has been applied? Try querying dba_registry.

Comment: Database says - patch is not applied.

Comment: Weird. Give us the output of: select DIRECTORY_NAME, DIRECTORY_PATH from dba_directories where directory_name like 'OPATCH%';

Comment: and try specifying the patch number and bundle series: datapatch -apply <patch_number> -force -bundle_series <bundle_series_number>

Comment: If that doesn't work, I'd suggest you should open an SR